# Nodejs is confilicting with Requirejs when using require

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I am new to requirejs I want to get rid of the conflict when calling require('fs').
I have read on http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html that I can use a config that will combine requirejs with mainjs into a new js file but I am not sure where to put that piece of code to make it work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using requirejs for node.js code when `require()` is built in.

Comment: I am using requirejs to have my javascript code in modules, my problem is :
whenever i want to use require from nodejs for example: require('fs'); it uses require from requirejs which gives an error

Comment: And that does not explain why you cannot just use `require()` as it supports node.js modules just fine.   I'm trying to figure out why you're attempting to use `requirejs()` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use require.js with node you should follow the [instructions for node](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html).

Basically you have to `npm i requirejs` and then (directly from the docs):

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

var foo = requirejs('foo');
var bar = requirejs('bar');
```